# Change the value in the double for loop or use linq

Tags: c#, linq

I want to write such double `for loop` for a two dimensional `List`, it threw a error `cannot be assigned to it is read only` then how to modify it?(Maybe we can build a new variable, but the type of `PositionList` is very complicated) By the way, is there a easy way to use the `linq` to change the `List`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < PositionList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < PositionList[i].Count; j++)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition - PositionList[i][j].Position) < T)
        {
            PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition = PositionList[i][j].Position;
            PositionList[i + 1][j].Position = PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the code for the `PositionList`, `pairList` and `AddTwoList` are existed Lists:

```
var PositionList = pairList.GroupBy(o => o.pair.Item1.Date)
                 .Select(o =>
                 {
                     int Position = 0;
                     var SumPosition = AddTwoList.GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                                                 .Select(p => new {                    
                                                     DesignPosition = p.Sum(q => q.DesignPosition),
                                                     Position                    
                                                 }).ToList();
                     return SumPosition;
                 }).ToList();
```

Comment: If either `DesignPosition` or `Position` is read-only (has only a getter but no setter) you can´t set its value, that´s all the error sais. Linq won´t do this neither.

Comment: Can you expose type of `PositionList` ?

Comment: Linq is used for querying and not assigning so for loops are good. As for the error... One of the properties you are trying to change are read-only... so change that

Comment: Your problem doesn't seem to be realted to looping or linqs. Your problem seems to be that you are trying to assign something to a read-only property (though its hard to be sure without the definitions).

Comment: You cannot access `PositionList[i + 1][j]` it will throw [index out of range exception](http://www.dotnetperls.com/indexoutofrangeexception)

Comment: @ Umair M sorry I will change it

Comment: Yeah - any time you use I+1 (in a loop), you need to either make the loop I=0;i=count-1 or if(I==count-1){thing = somethingBesidesI_Plus_1;}

Comment: @Gilad Green `PositionList` is obtained by `linq`, then how to change the read-only property

Comment: @user6703592 - it is probably an anonymous type returned from the linq that you created and that is why it is read only.... If you show some sample data and that linq maybe we can help

Comment: The only "writing" you're doing here is PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition = PositionList[i][j].Position;
            PositionList[i + 1][j].Position = PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition;
so look to those to mak sure they are not read only.

Comment: @ Gilad Green Exactly! So, is it possible to change the read only?

Comment: @user6703592 - No... but you can create a class instead of having it an anonymous type and then you will be able to - If you show some code of that linq then I will be able to show a proper example

Comment: @ Gilad Green I have showed the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So

1. As far as for using linq to update the objects - linq is for querying and not updating, so unless you want to create new objects in the `if` statement linq is not the direction.
2. As for your error of `cannot be assigned to it is read only` - The collection of objects you are using is generated by linq and is a collection of an anonymous type. **Anonymous type's properties are `read-only`**, which explains the error.

Without going into your linq logic the easiest way to solve is to create a class and that your linq will initialize instances of it instead of an anonymous type:

```
public class YourClass
{
    public int Position { get; set; }
    public int DesignPosition { get; set; }
}

var PositionList = pairList.GroupBy(o => o.pair.Item1.Date)
                           .Select(o => AddTwoList.GroupBy(p => p.Key)
                                                  .Select(p => new YourClass {                    
                                                      DesignPosition = p.Sum(q => q.DesignPosition),
                                                      Position = 0                   
                                                   }).ToList())
                           .ToList();

for (int i = 0; i < PositionList.Count - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < PositionList[i].Count; j++)
    {
        if (Math.Abs(PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition - PositionList[i][j].Position) < T)
        {
            PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition = PositionList[i][j].Position;
            PositionList[i + 1][j].Position = PositionList[i][j].DesignPosition;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @user6703592 - Did this help you?

Comment: @ Gilad Green Thank you a lot, but actually, `PositionList` include a lot of Anonymous type, so is it possible to avoid new class even create a new variable. Actually, I try to avoid the new class the whole program,

Comment: @user6703592 - _I try to avoid the new class the whole program_ - this approach is wrong.... why to avoid having classes but program in a strongly typed language?..

Comment: @user6703592 - without creating a specific class for it what you can do, which I recommend not to, is in the `if` to create new anonymous objects containing those new values and then having a list of those... but again I feel that is a bad solution